# shifting values of a column grouping by another column of the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataFrame that looks like the following:

```
page_id      content         name
1            {}              John
1            {cat, dog}      Anne
2            {}              Ethan
3            {}              John
3            {sea, earth}    Anne
3            {earth, green}  Ethan
4            {}              Mark
```

I need the value of the `content` column of each `page_id` to be equal to the value of the `content` column of the **next** `page_id`, only for the same page_ids. I suppose I need to use the `shift()` function al along with a group by `page_id`, but I don't know how to put it together.

The expected output would be:

```
page_id      content         name
1            {cat, dog}      John
1            NaN             Anne
2            NaN             Ethan
3            {sea, earth}    John
3            {earth, green}  Anne
3            NaN             Ethan
4            NaN             Mark
```

Any help on this issue will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the `groupby` apply given your sorting on `'page_id'`. `shift` everything then only set the values within group using `where`. This will be much faster as the number of groups becomes large.

```
df['content'] = df.content.shift(-1).where(df.page_id.eq(df.page_id.shift(-1)))

   page_id         content   name
0        1      {cat, dog}   John
1        1             NaN   Anne
2        2             NaN  Ethan
3        3    {earth, sea}   John
4        3  {earth, green}   Anne
5        3             NaN  Ethan
6        4             NaN   Mark
```

Comment: I really noted how this fastened the calculations. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want a `groupby` with `shift`:

```
df['content'] = df.groupby('page_id').content.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1))

     page_id         content
0      1.0      {cat, dog}
1      NaN             NaN
2      NaN             NaN
3      3.0    {earth, sea}
4      3.0  {green, earth}
5      NaN             NaN
6      NaN             NaN
```

Comment: It is close, but I don't want the shift() to act on the page_id column. Could you edit your answer so that this doesn't happen? Oh and, by the way, there are more columns in the dataframe, I just didn't show them for the calculation. I would like the final output to keep them, see the edit I just did on the dataframe and the expected output.